# Set cols attribute for Textarea in ZendForm

Tags: zend-framework

This is my code to display a textarea  in zendform. I show fine textarea with desired rows but if i set attribute for cols it does not add columns in it.
Code is this:

```
$element = $this->CreateElement('textarea', 'description');
$element->setAttrib('rows', '4');
$element->setAttrib('cols', '8');
$element->setLabel('Comment');
```

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1. The code for setting the "cols" is commented out (// in front of the line)
2. are you sure that you do not set the width of the textarea in a stylesheet? Because the width overwrites the cols set in your markup.

Comment: Very smart :-<
I know that at th begining of cols line there is //.
I did not remove it only so that it will provide help to others

Comment: try this code:

    $this->addElement('textarea', 'description', array('cols' => '4', 'rows' => '4'));

Answer (score 1):

Use :

```
$text = new Zend_Form_Element_Textarea('Text');
$text->setOptions(array('cols' => '4', 'rows' => '4'));
```